# #pragma vector directive ignored on iar rh850 compiler

Tags: interrupt-handling, iar

I'm using IAR RH850 compiler and I'm in the process of implementing the interrupt routines. It seems I have written everything by the book, but the interrupt jumps to the default interrupt handler (loop) instead of my handler. I did it the same as with other IAR projects, I wrote the interrupt routine with the `#pragma vector` directive with the vector offset and `__interrupt` keyword.

```
#pragma vector=0x100
__interrupt void ISR_CustomHandler(void)
{
  __DI();
  InterruptRoutine();
  __EI();
}
```

In the header file I have:

```
#include <intrinsics.h>
#pragma language=extended
#include <iorh850.h>
__interrupt void ISR_CustomHandler();
```

In the linker output file it looks like it was registered (address is correct):

```
___interrupt_0x10       0x0000941c    0x2  Code  Wk  default_handler.o [4]
___interrupt_0x100      0x000087d0         Code  Gb  RH850.o [1]
___interrupt_0x101      0x0000941c    0x2  Code  Wk  default_handler.o [4]
```

Is there anything else I should be aware of?

On interrupt CPU jumps to 0x100, which is correct. But jump from this location on is incorrect - it looks like the linker ignored my custom handler. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set the TB bit in the corresponding Interrupt Control register (ICCxxxx) for each ISR that you want to be called via the table or modify the default handler to determine which ISR to call and call it from within the default handler. From your problem discription, I think you want to use the table method (set corresponding TB bit in the corresponding ICC interrupt control register.